# how to display dropdown on cart page based on category?

Tags: cart

This is my cart page
[image: cart page]

Here i have added 3 dropdown list which is static and i want to show first 2 dropdown based on category "rings"

any solution?

Comment: rings products?

Comment: yes "rings" is a category

Comment: Means display "rings" category in dropdown or display all sub categories?

Comment: what you want to display subcategories or products?

Comment: I want that the dropdown which you see in the image should be shown only when customer has given order for any rings. This is jwellery shop website so there are many items and "ring" is one of the category under which products that is rings are shown

Comment: if dropdowns are static then you can display it as per the particular category id

Comment: yes i know but how??

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to display 2 dropdown if a product from a specified category, is added in cart. To achieve that, a have build for you a simple module.

First let's declare our module in `/etc/modules/Namespace_CheckCategoryOnCart.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_CheckCategoryOnCart>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_CheckCategoryOnCart>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next, in `/app/code/local/Namespace/Namespace` we have the following structure

```
/app/code/local/Namespace/Namespace/etc/config.xml
```

Contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_CheckCategoryOnCart>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_CheckCategoryOnCart>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <checkcategory>
                <class>Namespace_CheckCategoryOnCart_Helper</class>
            </checkcategory>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Helper class:

```
/app/code/local/Namespace/Namespace/Helper/Data.php
```

Contains

```
<?php
class Namespace_CheckCategoryOnCart_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function hasProductFromCategory(){
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $categoryIds = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
            foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId){
                if($categoryId == "YOUR_RINGS_CATEGORY_ID"){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your `cart.phtml` you can check this condition using the following code:

```
if(Mage::helper('checkcategory')->hasProductFromCategory()){
      //show your dropdown
}
```